# Can't scroll with laptop "pointing stick"

Tags: virtualbox, mouse-scroll

I'm using ubuntu in virtualbox and cannot scroll. What can I do?

**EDIT:** My host is Windows 7. I'm using a laptop (Lenovo ThinkPad X201s) and I'm trying to scroll not with a mouse wheel but with the [red dot which function as a mouse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointing_stick).

Comment: What is your "host" operating system?

Comment: Did you install guest additions?

Comment: @flute: My host is Windows 7. Just added it to my question. Thanks

Comment: @ulidtko Yes. I installed the guest additions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem solved. Here's how:

- In your host (Windows), go to the SynTP folder. Probably C:\Program Files\Synaptics\SynTP
- Locate the file TP4table.dat and copy it to your desktop (or to somewhere else).

[image: locate the file]

- Open your copy of TP4table.dat and find the line marked in blue in the following screenshot (line 26, right after all the ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;).

[image: find the marked line]

- put the following line in there:  `*,*,VirtualBox.exe,*,*,*,WheelStd,0,9`

[image: the new line added]

- Now replace the original TP4table.dat (in C:\Program Files\Synaptics\SynTP) with the modified one (you can backup the original before you replace it).
- restart your computer.
- The thing works.

Answer (score 1):

Can You please try the instructions mentioned in the following links:

http://aaronpace.blogspot.com/2010/10/trackpoint-and-virtualbox.html

[http://kailapis.wordpress.com/2009/08/20/trackpoint-with-virtualbox.html](http://kailapis.wordpress.com/2009/08/20/trackpoint-with-virtualbox)

They seem to work as the problem is with Windows drivers

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.